# Composition of n only using 2 numbers

Tags: combinatorics

In how many distinct ways can you decompose n to a sum of 1's or 2's ?

For example if n is 3, the number of ways to decompose it, is 3 : ( (1,1,1),(1,2),(2,1) )

Can somebody give out the formula ?

Comment: I recommend decomposing $4,5$ and looking for a pattern.  Similar idea: take the sums for $3$, add $1$ to each, then find out if any are missing for $4$ (there are two ways to "add one", but there may be overlaps).

Comment: This should be the Fibonacci numbers. Hint: Write down a recursion $n(k) = n(k-1) + n(k -2)$ for $k \geq 2$ where $n(k)$ denotes the number of decompositions.

Comment: @Yasser I think it will be $n(k) = \frac{\phi^{k+1} - (-\phi)^{-(k+1)}}{\sqrt{5}}$ where $\phi = 1 + \sqrt{5}$. $0$ admits $n(0) = 1$ decompositions $\{()\}$ and $1$ admits $n(1) = 1$ decompositions $\{(1)\}$. From there on you have to solve the recursion I wrote in my other comment. For a solution of the recursion see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression.

Comment: @Yasser BTW: Under https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Combinatorial_proofs you will find your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of getting the recursion:

For any number $n$, its composition is either going to end with a $1$ or a $2$, but if we remove that final digit we will get the composition for $n-1$ and $n-2$ respectively. Hence
$$N(n)=N(n-1)+N(n-2).$$